# How to Disable Visual Studio 2012 to opening a STS Server(Like Local STS)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, wif

I have enabled the WIF using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/10/23/windows-identity-foundation-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-rtm.aspx) tool. It allows me to open a Local STS server when I press F5. How to disable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the only solution I found is to disable this extension from Tools > Extension and Updates